# Sub setting data frame by group means

Tags: r

I would like to subset a data frame by group means. I want to subset all data values greater than the group mean. The code I have tried is:

```
data<-read.csv("TreeData.csv")

library(plyr)
#Calculating the group means
MDBH<-ddply(data, .(PLTPA),summarise, MDBH=mean(DBH))
MDBH
dataDHT<-subset(data,DBH>MDBH)
#The subset data is incorrect, it excluded some value greater than the mean    
and included some values less than the mean.
dataDHT
```

The data set I created for this problem is at:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ejnjhg4ogk2g4rw/TreeData.csv?dl=0

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: There is no sense in your code. `MDBH` is a `data.frame` and isn't part of `data`. More over, `ddply` returns a grouped results with less rows than in `data`. Not to mention that you've calculated mean per group, so how each observation in `data` will relate to its mean in `MDBH` while in `subset`? Finally, we don't need to download your data from dropbox. You cab create a simple reproducible example using the built in data sets in R such as `mtcars`. Here's an example how to solve your problem  `mtcars$indx <- with(mtcars, ave(mpg, cyl, FUN = mean)) ; mtcars[mtcars$mpg < mtcars$indx, ]`

Comment: Thank you for writing more about how dumb I am and less about the code that solves the problem.

Comment: I wasn't trying to tell you that you dumb, rather explain you whats wrong with your solution. Hope you were able to use the code on your real data. Cheers